# How to execute a callback when the result of a logical statement changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, conditional-statements

With jquery is it possible to have a function being fired as soon as a conditional statement turns from false to true?

I am looking for a solution that does not consume all the system's resources (ie: Not `setInterval(function(){},1)` ).

**In the end** I used .scroll() rather than the more ambitious suggestions below.

Comment: if( $('#lay3b_top').scrollTop() + $('#lay3b_top').height() == $('#measuring_wrapper').height()) { }

The trouble is the conditions are complex and don't have any associated and convenient trigger.

Comment: @Patrick Beardmore: But you agree that event triggers are a better solution, don’t you?

Comment: Sure, I just can't think of any. The conditional statement decides if a <div> is scrolled to the bottom or not.

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, but your solution is definitely wrong!

Comment: @markus: That solution is meant to be what I don't want to do (hence "not")

Comment: I'd agree with @Harnish. Seems like the onscroll event is exactly what's needed.

Comment: @Hamish I will try onscroll now

Comment: @Hamish    .scroll() is what I was looking for. I'm also very interested in the other solutions for this general idea of binding functions to conditional statements.

Comment: @patrick. yeah, maybe you could edit a few suggestions into your question about what you might do or might have tried and a scenario which describes the practical case you're solving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the height of an element is changed, you only need to observe the *resize* and *scroll* events. So try this:

```
$(window).bind('resize', handler);
$(document).bind('scroll', handler);
```

Since these events can be fired quite often, you should keep the handler operations at a minimum. You could, for example, cache the `$` calls using a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)):

```
var handler = (function(a, b){
    return function(event) {
        if ((a.scrollTop() + a.height()) == b.height()) {
            /* … */
        }
    })($('#lay3b_top'), $('#measuring_wrapper'));
```

Here the variables `a` and `b` inside the inner function that is returned by the outer function are bound to the return values of `$('#lay3b_top')` and `$('#measuring_wrapper')` respectively. `(function(){})()` is an anonymous function expression that is immediately called with the given arguments to bind the arguments to the function’s scope.

Comment: It should be noted that browsers can fire a whole lot of "scroll" events, so it's a good idea to keep the handler as fast as possible and definitely avoid DOM manipulation (or defer it).

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, absolutely. The jQuery objects could be cached in this case, for example: `var handler = (function(){ return function(event) {if ((arguments[0].scrollTop()+arguments[0].height()) == arguments[1].height()) { /* … */ } })($('#lay3b_top'), $('#measuring_wrapper'));`